# Выдает ошибку TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

```
a= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
n = ''
res = ''
key =  1
enter = input('').strip()
def add (f):
    if f != '':
        f = int(f)
        f += key
        f = str(f)
        return f
    else:
        return n


for i in enter:
    if a.count(i) == 0:
        if i.isnumeric():
            n += i
        else:
            n = add(n)
            res += n 
            n= ''
            res += i
    else: 
        n = add(n)
        res += n
        n = ''
        res += a([(a.index(i)+key)%len(a)])

n = add(n)
res += n 
n =''
print(res)
```

Не знаю как исправить ошибку в строке:

```
res += a([(a.index(i)+key)%len(a)])
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PYCHARM PROGRAm/1/venv/Scripts/1333213213213.py", line 29, in <module>
    res += a([(a.index(i)+key)%len(a)])
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

P.S Немного сути программы- Это шифратор цезаря. Когда я ввожу abc11, оно должно выводить bcd12. То есть + 1 знак/цифру.

Comment: res += a[(a.index(i)+key)%len(a)] Там не нужны круглые скобки после a, это ведь не функция.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
n = ''
res = ''
key =  1

enter = input('').strip()
abc11

def add (f):
    if f != '':
        f = int(f)
        f += key
        f = str(f)
        return f
    else:
        return n

for i,z in enumerate(enter):
    if a.count(z) == 0:
        if z.isnumeric():
            n += z
        else:
            n = add(n)
            res += n
            n= ''
            res += z
    else:
        n = add(n)
        res += n
        n = ''
        res += a[(a.index(z)+key)%len(a)]


n = add(n)
res += n
n =''
print(res)
bcd12
```

Comment: for i,z in enumerate(enter): Что делает в данной строчке i , так как она нигде не задействована, а без неё не работает? А так БОЛЬШОЕ ТЕБЕ спасибо тебе брата) Очень выручил)

Answer (score 3):

Круглые скобки после идентификатора (имени переменной) означают вызов функции. `a` в этой строке не функция, а строка, вы пытаетесь вызвать строку как функцию, о чем и говорит ошибка:

```
res += a([(a.index(i)+key)%len(a)])
```

Самые внешние круглые скобки не нужны. Правильно так:

```
res += a[(a.index(i)+key)%len(a)]
```